# Symfony 4 custom exception handler for certain controllers

Tags: php, symfony, exception

From my understanding there can only be one exception handler which will catch all unhandled exceptions. However, is there an elegant way to have a specific exception handler for Controllers A and B, and controllers C, D, etc. would be handled by default exception handler?

Comment: You can have as many [kernel.exception](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#working-with-the-kernel-exception-event) listeners as you want.  If your A/B controllers throw their own specific exceptions then it's easy to catch them.  Basically it is what the security system does for things like AccessDeniedExceptions.  Without a custom exception then your exception handler would probably have to poke around in the $request object to try and see which controller was used.

Comment: Is there a way to know in Execption controller in which controller the exception was thrown?

Comment: Not that I am aware of which is why I suggested looking at the request object.  You should be able to pull the _controller info which usually indicates the controller.  But I think a custom exception might be cleaner.  Perhaps you could describe why you need this sort of functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible by default, other than creating a kernel eventlistener. However, you can create something simple yourself.

In a Controller Method, you might could do something like

```php
public function index() 
{
    try {
       // Do normal logic here.
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
       // Do whatever you want with any exception. 
       // Or Call your exception handler: MyExceptionHandler::handle()
    }
}
```

You can also create a custom `AbstractController` so it might be a bit simpler. In which you extend the render function, so you abstract that logic away